Why httpd can read files with tag "httpd_sys_content_t" in SELinux?
I used the below command to check related policy rules, and only find the following 2 related rules:
[root@system1 home]# sesearch -A -s httpd_t -t httpd_sys_content_t -ds -dt
allow httpd_t httpd_sys_content_t:dir { ioctl lock read };
allow httpd_t httpd_sys_content_t:lnk_file { getattr read };

Procceses in httpd_t domain can only read dir and lnk_file with httpd_sys_content_t tag... Does this mean in SELinux dir actually contains all the files inside it?
I tried to search for the definiation of "dir" in SELinux on the internet but couldn't find a thing.
OS: RHEL 9
SELinux Policy: Targeted

The output you've shown is the standard SELinux configuration. You need to check the SELinux context of the files httpd can't read (ls -lZ /path/to/directory). The files should have the context httpd_sys_content_t (read-only) or httpd_sys_rw_content_t (read-write). To check SELinux denials you can run ausearch -m avc -ts recent (that lists denials in the last ten minutes).

Now I know what's going on.
SELinux has a concept called "attribute". Type httpd_sys_content_t has an attribute called httpd_content_type, and there is a rule that allows httpd_t to read files with the httpd_content_type attribute. Then, as long as there is a type with this httpd_content_type attribute, all the rules defined for the attribute will be automatically applied to the containing type.


This answer doesn't address the key point of the question; what is the role of dir?
